# bubblesort alg using an array

Tags: java, arrays, int, bubble-sort

Okay so I've pretty much been working on this for a while today and I know it's very close to being completed. I'm stuck on trying to find an escape clause where I'm able to finally return the list. This is all the code I've worked on.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package algorithm;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class Algorithm {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private static int list[] = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Algorithm alg = new Algorithm();
        alg.bubblesort(list);
    }

    public Algorithm() {
    }

    public int[] bubblesort(int[] i) {
        for (int a = 0; a < i.length;) {
            for (int b = 1; b < i.length + 1;) {
                int currentNumber = i[a];
                if (b < i.length) {
                    if (currentNumber > i[b]) {
                        i[a] = i[b];
                        i[b] = currentNumber;
                        a++;
                        b++;
                    } else if (currentNumber < i[b]) {
                        a++;
                        b++;
                    }
                } else if (b == i.length) {
                    a = 0;
                    b = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    public void isSorted(int[] i) {
        for (int x = 0; x < i.length;) {
            if (i[x + 1] < i[i.length - 1]) {
                if (i[x] < i[x + 1]) {
                    x++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i));
    } 
}
```

Okay so my question is how can I get to return the final sorted list?

Comment: @StephenD theres nothing wrong with homework as long as he tried to show some effort.

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: This does not look like a bubble sort; a bubble sort should only compare and swap items that are next to each other. Can you explain your algorithm in words?

Comment: oh damn my question didn't show :O my bad

Comment: @Joni I am comparing items next to each other within the list though. That happens here if (currentNumber > i[b]) {

                    i[a] = i[b];
                    i[b] = currentNumber;

                    a++;
                    b++;

Comment: and I swap the items inside the list

Comment: Generally, i and j are used as loop counters, not a and b... it's kinda disturbing

Comment: @StephenD I didn't represent my question clearly which is why I've been mistaken here sorry. This isn't homework or anything this is just me practicing during my vacation.

Comment: @Julien Your right, people commonly use i and j as loop counters but hey it isn't illegal not to name your loop counters differently, but you do see the comparison and swapping of elements happening right?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza posted the question now

Comment: @Kevin I did all of this. This is no homework or anything. I am on vacation using my time wisely to code algorithms such as bubblesort. I think i've been mistaken due to not showing my question a lot clearly haha.

Comment: So at all points you have `b==a+1`? The fact that you have two different variables and two different for-loops obscures this fact. It would be clearer to use just `a` and write `a+1` where you have `b`.

Comment: @Joni your spot on with that, I didn't realise than till late.

Comment: @Joni The reason why my bubblesort has been complicated is because it only does one pass. For example if I have the numbers 5,4,3,2,1 it will give me the final list of 4,3,2,1,5 and stop there which is what I don't want. I've been trying to get it to complete the whole bubblesort and i've even tried using recursion but that becomes hard for me to manage as it does sort the list but infinitely. I'd appreciate if you can give me any guidance on how to get the algorithm to sort the whole list rather than partially.

Comment: It's impossible to sort an array in a single pass, or even a constant number of passes. That would imply O(n) time complexity; sorting is at least O(n log n), and bubble sort is O(n²).

Comment: A common stopping condition for bubble sort is counting the number of swaps made in the inner loop: if no swaps aremade the array is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do a bubble sort is to use a `while` loop, so that you don't have to embed `for` loops.

Give this a try:

```
public int[] bubblesort(int[] i) {
    int temp;
    int a = 0;

    while(a < (i.length - 1)) {
        if(i[a+1] < i[a]) {
            //Swap i[a] with i[a+1]
            temp = i[a];
            i[a] = i[a+1];
            i[a+1] = temp;
            //Reset counter
            a = 0;
        } else {
            //Increment counter if two elements are already in order
            a++;
        }
    }

    return i;
}
```

EDIT: For yours try adding this in there:

```
if(a == (i.length-1) {
    break;
}
```

This should break out of the looping once your outer loop gets to the end (meaning it should be sorted). The code would look like this:

```
public int[] bubblesort(int[] i) {
    for (int a = 0; a < i.length;) {
        for (int b = 1; b < i.length + 1;) {
            int currentNumber = i[a];
            if (b < i.length) {
                if (currentNumber > i[b]) {
                    i[a] = i[b];
                    i[b] = currentNumber;
                    a++;
                    b++;
                } else if (currentNumber < i[b]) {
                    a++;
                    b++;
                }
            } else if (b == i.length) {
                a = 0;
                b = 1;
            }
        }
        //Break out of loop when it gets to the end
        if(a == (i.length - 1)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: that's a neat looking way of doing it. Though in my case I can't seem to find a way to get to return the list I keep reiterating the for loops over and over again even when the list is already sorted. Can you think of a way to maybe try enable that in my case without having to adapt most of what I did with your one or else it would mean I didn't code the heart of the algorithm for my practice haha. If you know what I mean.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work. There's one reason why my bubblesort became this complex is because it only did one stage. So for example if I have the numbers 5,4,3,2,1 and I do the common bubblesort it would float 5 to the top with the list being 4,3,2,1,5 and it would stop there. Thanks for trying :). If you do find another solution please feel free to post.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should decide that whether (1) you directly change `list` or (2) not.

```
alg.bubblesort(list);
```

I think this sentence means (1) because you aren't catching the result. if you want to do (2), it should be

```
int[] result = alg.bubblesort(list);
```

and, if (1) is better, fix the defenition `bubblesort`

```
public void bubblesort (int[] args)
```

In addition, you should not use `int[] i` because variable `i` often means the index of array.

Comment: Oh, my answer didn't make any sense.. I fixed it now.

Comment: I want to do 1. I have changed the unconventional way I named my parameter to what you have suggested though I'm still unsure of how to directly change list. I've been trying to create a condition that will enable it to stop looping through the for-loop and came up with using another method isSorted with the idea to call that inside the bubblesort method which would check every value of each index whether it's lesser than the next and if all are then return the list. It's not shown like that in the code above because I then had given up on it and did other things and now there's no link

Comment: Your algorithm is definitely not a bubble sort, but I think it's make sense. It should be changed `void isSorted` to `boolean isSorted`, but it is so inefficient to call `isSorted` method every time of for-loop...   Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Ah okay, no worries :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a bubble sort implemented in Java....

```
public class BubbleSort {

static int intArray[] = { 10, 5, 100, 1, 10000 };

public static void doSort() {
    for (int outer = 0; outer < intArray.length; outer++) {
        for (int inner = 0; inner < intArray.length - outer- 1; inner++) {
            if (intArray[inner] > intArray[inner + 1]) {
                int temp = intArray[inner];
                intArray[inner] = intArray[inner + 1];
                intArray[inner + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void printArray() {
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("  " + intArray[i]);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.print("Array Before Sorting->");
    printArray();
    doSort();
    System.out.print("\nArray After Sorting ->");
    printArray();
}
```

}

For detailed explanation of the above program and bubble sort in general please have a look at the link - http://www.javabrahman.com/algorithms-in-java/bubble-sort-in-java/